# How to use parentheses with objects in scripts with vb.et

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, scripting

Im doing a program that creates dynamic code from static code elements that I had in the project like variables, arrays, subroutines, functions etc...

for example, code like this:

```
 Do
     id = id + 1 
     bandera = bandera + 1
     arreglo = valvula(id) 'this is a function
 Loop Until (bandera = 100)
```

Where id, bandera, arreglo and valvula are static code elements of my program

Surfing on internet I found that I can use scripts in vb.net using msscriptcontrol, thats why I made this example:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Public Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    Dim VBScript As MSScriptControl.ScriptControl
    Public valor As Double
    Public VBCode As String
    Public otro(2) As Double
    Public nuevo As New Dictionary(Of Integer, nodo)
    Public prueba As New nodo

    Private Sub Command1_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles Command1.Click
        On Error GoTo line1
        VBScript.AddCode(VBCode)
        Exit Sub
    line1:
        MsgBox(Err.Number & Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "error")
        Err.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim prueba As New nodo
        otro(0) = 0
        prueba.uno = 1
        prueba.dos = 1
        nuevo.Add(1, prueba)
        VBScript = New MSScriptControl.ScriptControl
        VBScript.Language = "VBScript"
        VBScript.AddObject("Form1", Me)
        VBScript.AllowUI = True
    End Sub

    Function funcion(ByVal valores As Double) As Double
        valores = valores + 1
        funcion2()
        Return valores
    End Function

    Function valvula(ByVal dato1 As Integer, ByVal dato2 As Integer, ByVal dato3 As Integer) As Double()
        dato1 = dato1 + 1
        dato2 = dato2 + 1
        dato3 = dato3 + 1
        valvula = New Double() {dato1, dato2, dato3}
    End Function
End Class

Public Class nodo
    Public uno As Integer
    Public dos As Integer
End Class

Module Module1
    Public variable1 As Double = 120
    Public Sub funcion2()
        variable1 = variable1 + 1
        MsgBox(variable1)
    End Sub
End Module
```

But I had a few questions:

1.- When I try to to compile and execute this kind of lines:

```
form1.otro(0) = 0
MsgBox(form1.nuevo(1).dos)
```

My program show me the following error: "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment", I would like to know why I cannot use parentheses to work with an especific index of the elements that I call from "form1".

2.- I would like to know how to call elements like public variables, functions or other stuff declared in standard vb modules.

Comment: have you tried creating an instance of form1?  'otro' and 'nuevo' are not static (Shared), so they should require an instance in order to be referenced.  If you dont create a form instance, FormLoad does not run and so, 'nuevo` has zero elements (making `nuevo(1)` an illegal ref), which might be the cause of some of the problems.

Comment: Hi Plutonix, in the example nuevo is a vb dictionary. Im gonna check about the instance, but this problem only happend when I try to use an especific index of arrays or dictionaries declared in form1

Comment: In the line VBScript.AddObject("Form1", Me) I add form1 as an object to use inside the script. If you see the example I made a function with the name valvula that return an array, I can use lines like "form1.otro = form1.valvula(1,2,3)", where I assign the array that "valvula" return directly to the array otro. But the problem is when I try to use an index of any elements (arrays, vb dictionary, etc...) from "form1"